# React server rendering escaped value

Tags: reactjs

I'm using reacjs server rendering in an entry point, I have the following code corresponding to the default template:

```
import React from 'react/addons';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {

        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>{this.props.title}</title>
                    <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                    <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximun-scale=1, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700" type="text/css" />
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/default.min.css" />
                </head>
                <body>
                    {this.props.children}
                    <script>
                        var __api = "http://localhost:7002";
                    </script>
                    <script src="/public/js/vendor.min.js"></script>
                    {this.props.feet}
                </body>
            </html>
        );
    }
});
```

When running in the browser this part

```
var __api = "http://localhost:7002";
```

it's rendered as

```
<script data-reactid=".oq6es39jwg.1.1">var __api = &quot;http://localhost:7002&quot;;</script>
```

Anybody knows what I'm missing?

Comment: Just one other idea is to create a text file with the standard HTML, and insert the result of the render call into that content. If you follow the isomorphic pattern, it may be easier to manage than the answer you accepted.

Comment: I don't get it @WiredPrairie, how could I possibly print javascript code to make it work inside an input text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check out this https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html for more info.

Comment: This is awsome, a simply `<script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: 'var __api = "http://localhost:7002"'}}></script>` and it works like magic!